# What am I doing wrong with series.replace()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replace integer values in pd.Series with other integer values as follows. I am using dict-like replace:

```
ser_list = [pd.Series([65, 1, 0, 0, 1]), pd.Series([0, 62, 1, 1, 0])]
for ser in ser_list:
    ser.replace({65: 10, 62: 20})
```

I am expecting the result:

```
[10, 1, 0, 0, 1] # first series in the list
[0, 20, 1, 1, 0] # second series in the list
```

where 65 should be replaced with 10 in the first series, and 62 should be replaced with 20 in the second.

However, in with this code it is returning the original series without any replacement. Any clue why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, by `inplace=True`:

```
for ser in ser_list:
    ser.replace({65: 10, 62: 20}, inplace=True)
    
print (ser_list)
[0    10
1     1
2     0
3     0
4     1
dtype: int64, 0     0
1    20
2     1
3     1
4     0
dtype: int64]
```

But not recommended like mentioned @Dan in comments - [link](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace):

> The pandas core team discourages the use of the **inplace** parameter, and eventually it will be deprecated (which means "scheduled for removal from the library"). Here's why:
>
> **inplace** won't work within a method chain.
> The use of **inplace** often doesn't prevent copies from being created, contrary to what the name implies.
> Removing the **inplace** option would reduce the complexity of the pandas codebase.

Or assign to same variable in list comprehension:

```
ser_list = [ser.replace({65: 10, 62: 20}) for ser in ser_list]
```

Loop solution is possible with append to new list and assign back:

```
out = []
for ser in ser_list:
    ser = ser.replace({65: 10, 62: 20})
    out.append(ser)
    
print (out)
[0    10
1     1
2     0
3     0
4     1
dtype: int64, 0     0
1    20
2     1
3     1
4     0
dtype: int64]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `Series.map` with `fillna` and `list comprehension`:

```
new = [ser.map({65: 10, 62: 20}).fillna(ser) for ser in ser_list]

print(new)
[0    10.0
1     1.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     1.0
dtype: float64, 0     0.0
1    20.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     0.0
dtype: float64]
```